# Insert data into multiple table MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I am new about MVC+EF

I need to insert data into 3 table at a time but can not Figure out how can I do this
My data model is

```
public class UserLogin
    {
        [Key]public int UserID { get; set; }
        public string LoginName { get; set; }
        public byte Password { get; set; }
    }
    public class UserDetails
    {
        [Key]
        public int DetailID { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("UserLogin")]
        public int UserID { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
    }
    public class UserType
    {
        [Key]
        public int TypeID { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("UserLogin")]
        public int UserID { get; set; }
        public string TypeName { get; set; }
        public string TypeDiscription { get; set; }
    }
    public class UserBDCon : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<UserLogin> logins { get; set; }
        public DbSet<UserDetails> Detail { get; set; }
        public DbSet<UserType> Type { get; set; }
    }
```

Can anyone tell me how does look the controller and view file for this model ?

Comment: Have you attempted anything other than the above?

Comment: You can use stored procedure for inserting data in 3 tables on one procedure execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create additional properties in your model classes:

And data model should like this:

```
public class UserLogin
{
    [Key]
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string LoginName { get; set; }
    public byte Password { get; set; }
}
public class UserDetails
{
    [Key]
    public int DetailID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserLogin")]
    public int UserID { get; set; }

    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }

    //additional
    public UserLogin UserLogin { get; set; }
}
public class UserType
{
    [Key]
    public int TypeID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UserLogin")]
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string TypeName { get; set; }
    public string TypeDiscription { get; set; }

    //additional
    public UserLogin UserLogin { get; set; }
}
```

Example (without unit of work and repository but single context):

```
    UserBDCon db = new UserBDCon();

    var userLogin = new UserLogin() {LoginName = "Admin", Password = new byte()};
    var details = new UserDetails() {Address = "Address", UserName = "Admin", UserLogin = userLogin};
    var type = new UserType() {TypeDiscription = "Description", TypeName = "TypeName", UserLogin = userLogin};

    db.logins.Add(userLogin);
    db.Detail.Add(details);
    db.Type.Add(type);

    db.SaveChanges(); // EF insert data into 3 table at a time
```

You should use same db context. Queries in that case will be part of same transaction.
Would be better implement repository pattern and unit of work for goals single transaction like this http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Answer (score 0):

I must create new class which would contain all this classes something like this:

```
public class ViewModel()
{
   public IList<UserLogin> LoginModel {get; set;}
   public IList<UserDetails> DetailsModel {get; set;}
   public IList<UserType> TypeModel {get; set;}
}
```

And you must return this model return View(ViewModel) and create strongly tiped view than you can bind tables like this:

```
foreach(var item in ViewModel.LoginModel)
{

}
```